# Excel file left open

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

I broke something...

I have code that opens, writes and saves an excel file, usually inside a try-except construct for safety. I took out the try-except construct to test something, the code didn't run correctly and the file didn't close. Now there is a file that I cannot overwrite, delete or rename because is still 'open by another user'. Does anyone know how I can force the closure of this file or delete it?

Comment: Close python. Also you should try and use `with` when dealing with files to make sure they are closed correctly.

Comment: Thank you. That did it! When you say with, do you mean making the excel writer function a contextmanager?

Comment: Can't tell exactly, it depends on what you're using to access a file, but general syntax is `with open(<filename>) as <name>:` Here `with` will handle correct opening and closing of your file objects when required. More in PEP 343 (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/)